# load_model in Keras does not work in production server with Flask API

Tags: python, flask, keras

I have built a neural network with Keras with `Sequential()` and I have integrated in a Flask API. I have one endpoint for the training and one for do the individual predictions, in the latter I call the following function:

```
def prediction(x):
    K.clear_session()
    model = load_model('..//model.h5')
    pred = model.predict_proba(x)
    K.clear_session()
    return pred
```

When I call this endpoint locally, it works, but in the production server it does not, this error arises:

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(393, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

I have called `clear_session` twice because I read in other questions that it solves a similar problem, but not for me.

In the production server there are tons of calls to this endpoint each minute.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I just have to upload the version of tensorflow to the 2.4.1 and have the structure for the neuronal network and predict function given in the following post: https://medium.com/swlh/deep-learning-in-production-a-flask-approach-7a8e839c25b9